# How do you post a link to user's inbox in Facebook?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a iPhone application developer. I don't know how to send an "link" to a selected user's inbox in Facebook from my Facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send messages using a Facebook API from the backend, but you can do through JS SDK or redirecting user to facebook url as per this link

FYI: [Send Message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if I understood your question, but: If you want to provide a link that a user follows in order to go to her/his Facebook inbox, you can use the URL scheme `fb://mailbox` (provided that she/he has the Facebook app installed)

Answer (score 0):

As @Venu wrote, the api does not allow apps to send messages on the behalf of the user, only with the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) which you should be able to open using the [iOS sdk Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/dialog/).

Another approach you can use is the [Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) with which you can send messages on the behalf of the user, it requires the `xmpp_login` permission and you to implement an xmpp client.